# need help in webpack output library

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, output

I'm a amateur about webpack.
I'm trying to use webpack output.library.
I want to use the React project production version in html file.

Here's my code.

## In my webpack-config file:

```
const defaultConfig = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');

output: {
    ...defaultConfig.module.output,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    library: "MyLib",
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
}
```

## In my index.js file:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory();
else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define([], factory);
else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["MyLib"] = factory();
else
    root["MyLib"] = factory();
```

})(self, function() {})

## In my index.html file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement('div', {},
                window.myLib.HomePage() // this is the react component in index.js file
            ),
            document.getElementById('main') // html element id
        );
    });
</script>
```

But the myLab is not defined.
I tried both window.myLab and myLab.

Please teach me how I have to do

Comment: Its kinda unclear with your examples above, but looks like you are trying to expose the module to global object, so it can be accessed from window. You might wanna take a look at [Webpack external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals)

Answer (score 0):

I think you spelled it MyLib with capital M